# Content not scrolling using position:absolute

Tags: css, scroll, position

On the site I'm working on, the content is not scrolling. So on a 1024 x 768 monitor the top of the image is not seen. How can I correct this?

http://kenerly.com/test/index.html

Comment: @MightyPork that's unlikely to be nessecary. That code *does* look like some sort of horrid Dreamweaver generated code, but he should be able to fix it without too much issue. Its just a positioning problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is: 
Add a min-height to your `div#main` like this and set the overflow to auto. Also set the `position` to `relative`. That way the Image of the cabin (`header`) will be located at the bottom of the `#main`-Container:

```
#main{
    min-height: 768px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

To avoid ugly scrollbars, never use `overflow: scroll`, always use `overflow: auto` instead. In this case as well, set

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    // The following values are not really necessary, 
    // as they are the default values or are calculated automatically 
    // to the same values, so feel free to remove them
    width: 100%; // automatically calculated by the #header's contents
    overflow: auto; // default value anyways
    height: 768px; // automatically calculated by the #header's contents
}
```

Comment: beat you by a minutes ;-). I imagine he'd be better off with an explicit width on `#header` than `overflow: auto` and `width: 100%` in this case.

Comment: damn you :P Though I provided some additional life wisdom of never using `overflow: scroll`. Booya!

Comment: actually, `overflow: auto` is the default value anyways, if no other styles are set, but for the sake of clearness I will leave it. The `width: 100%` and the `height: 768px` on the `#header` as it will fit to the size of its contents anyways, so I will revise my answer.

Comment: Using this css the cabin is no longer attached to the bottom left of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `min-height` on `#main` in pixels, and set it to `position: relative;`.

Then remove the `overflow: scroll` from the `#header` as its no longer nessecary.

That should clear it up.

```
#main {
  min-height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
}
```

Comment: Using this css the cabin is no longer attached to the bottom left of the page.

Comment: @user196815 please check again. In my tests it is. Are you sure you've added position: relative to #main? In the future, if you're able to create a jsfiddle (ideally a minimal test case) illustrating your problem, people can fork and edit it and actually *show* you the answer. You just have to take our word in this case that it *does* work. I went into chrome's devtools and made the changes I listed above, and it definitely does work, and sticks to the bottom of the page. Where & how are you testing this code?